# From an Excel list of event attendees spanning 10 years, how do I create another list that pulls the first year of attendance for all my attendees?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I have a list of guests that come to my events. The list contains 10 years worth of guest check-ins in order by date (ascending). Based on this list, I want to create another list that shows the year that a guest first attended my event.

For example, John attended my event in 2011, 2012, and 2013. Sam attended my event in 2012 and 2014. This means John was my new guest in 2011, and Sam was my new guest in 2014. It is safe to assume that guests use the same email each time they come to my event. Therefore, the list will look like this:

| Email | First Year of Attendance |
| --- | --- |
| john@live.com | 2011 |
| sam@live.com | 2012 |

How do I create a formula that will help me create this list?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Well you can use the formula `=MIN(range)` to get the lowest value in a range.

Answer (score 1):

Try a MINIFS formula like this.

```
=MINIFS(B:B,A:A,E8)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way for me to generate the list of unique names with a formula? There are about 2000 names so I want to find a way to populate them in the new list automatically (which would also make it easy for me to continue using this in the future when my attendees list grows)

Comment: You're welcome!  Use =UNIQUE().  It returns an array with the names.

Comment: You could also add a pivot table with the names and minimum date.  That would be a nice, clean approach, and it would give you more functionality.  I'll add another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a new example showing two approaches:

1. Use a combination of =UNIQUE() and =MINIFS() as shown in the range D5:E8.  This is functional, but as you add more data you'll have to keep updating the range on the UNIQUE formula and filling down the MINIFS formula.
2. Use a pivot table as shown in the range D17:E22.  Put the names field in the **Rows** and the date field in the **Values**.  When you put the date in the Values, it will probably default to Sum of Date, but click on it, go to the **Value Field Settings**, and change it to **Min**.

[image]